# Javascript return array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, return

```
function setup() {
  var names = [];
  var name = {firstname: "", lastname: ""};

  name.firstname = "John";
  name.lastname = "Doe";
  names.push(name);

  name.firstname = "Bill";
  name.lastname = "Smith";
  names.push(name);

  return names;
}

var temp = setup();
print temp[0].firstname;
```

I can't seem to figure out how to return an array of objects from a function. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

The problem is that the result stored in `temp` is the following:

```
 [
   {
     firstname: "Bill",
     lastname: "Smith"
   },
   {
     firstname: "Bill",
     lastname: "Smith"
   }
 ]
```

Comment: You are returning an array... that's why temp[0] works. What's the issue?

Comment: What makes you think something is wrong? What's happening?

Comment: Use `document.write( temp[0].firstname )`

Comment: you are pushing a reference to the same object into the `names` array, and overwriting the properties of that object. it will mean you have duplicate entries of bill smith in the output array.

Comment: FYI, aside from the fact that JS doesn't deep copy objects automatically, you can actually shorten your code a good bit by simply using a literal structure. No need for `.push()`. `var names = [{firstname: "john", lastname: "doe"}, {firstname: "bill": lastname: "smith"}];` You can also pass multiple items to `.push()` at once.

Answer (score 6):

You can't reuse name to push the "second" object because you haven't created a second object, it is the same object.  So name.firstname="Bill" is changing the first object not creating a second one.

```js
function setup() {
  var names = [];

  var name = {};
  name.firstname = "John";
  name.lastname = "Doe";
  names.push(name);

  var name2 = {};
  name2.firstname = "Bill";
  name2.lastname = "Smith";
  names.push(name2);

  return names;
}

var temp = setup();
alert(temp[0].firstname); // Alerts "John"
```

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 problems with your code.

1. To paint in console, you need to use `console.log(temp[0].firstname)` in place of `print`
2. You have a name object and you are updating it only. And as objects are passed by reference, both the instances at index 0 and index 1 are updated and have same value.

You need to update your code to following

```js
function setup() {
      var names = [];
      var n1 = {};
    
      n1.firstname = "John";
      n1.lastname = "Doe";
      names.push(n1);
    
      var n2 = {};
      n2.firstname = "Bill";
      n2.lastname = "Smith";
      names.push(n2);
    
      return names;
    }
    
    var temp = setup();
    console.log(temp[0].firstname);
```

Comment: @Downvoter - reason please

Comment: No idea what the downvoters problem was. This is a reasonable answer.

Comment: Hi, you answer is a plain copy of @Robert McKee's answer. Except you forgot to place a `)` at the end of your code.

Comment: @NikolayErmakov - I was holding back while posting this. But at the time I posted my answer Robert Mckee's answer did not had any explanation. And I wanted to add that. Whats wrong with that

Comment: Nothing wrong with this answer, and I've upvoted it as it is actually worded clearer than my own.

Comment: Don't forget to declare `n2` with `var`, or just reuse `n1` since you've already pushed the first object.

Comment: @squint - Thank you for adding that.

Comment: I upvoted the answer back